# Hyperledger fabric - Cant connect peer to channel - endorser client failed to connect - connection refused

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I created a testchannel and tried to join peer to it using the codes below.

```
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:7051

peer channel join -b testchannel.block
```

But connection error occured as below.

```
Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer1.org1.example.com:7051: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp 172.18.0.3:7051: connect: connection refused"
```

I tried the solutions mentioned in other similar posts such as changing the CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED but it still occured. How to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to check the docker log of the peer

```
docker logs <container id>
```

There is insufficient information provided to help you.

Comment: Thank you @Christopher . Sorry for the insufficient information. I reinstalled the docker and HyperLedger Fabric and the problem has gone.